# Comparing input with a list to see if there's word inside a word

Tags: string, list

Going to get the first two letters of the input and compare it with every word inside the list and if those first two letters of the input are present inside any of the words in the list, it will append to another list

i didn't try anything cuz idk wtf is going on pls help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any programming language, but used Python in another question, I will provide my answer in Python:

```py
words = ["Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]
def beginsWith(word, letters):
    return word[:len(letters)] == letters
result = []
letters = "Ba"
for word in words:
    if beginsWith(word, letters):
        result.append(word)
print(result) # Expected: ["Bar", "Baz"]
```